# Relaunching a jar from within itself?

Tags: java, jar, execute, relaunch

I am looking to relaunch a program I've written programmatically without knowing the name of the jar it's contained in. I know there's a way to do it if it's a class by doing `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javaw", getClass().getName()});` but how would I do it with a jar. I thought about running the class using the -cp argument but even then I still need the name of the jar. I'm actually thinking it's not possible given that the name of the jar has no programmatical significance but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use System.getProperty("java.class.path") to get the class path used to launch 'this' program.